# SQLite database file type missing from Visual Studio 2010 data source options

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sqlite, database-connection

I installed a x86/x64 official SQLite NuGet package on Visual Studio 2010 by following these instructions:
http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2012/11/10/SQLite-on-Visual-Studio-with-NuGet-and-Easy-Instructions.aspx. Then saved and built the project.

I try then to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model into the project and add a new database connection but I don't see a SQLite Database File under the data source options.

**How can I add the SQLite Database File to appear under the Visual Studio data source options**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I add the answer here myself since I just found it out:

After installing the NuGet package, I downloaded the setup package "Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)" from here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki. It was saying that "This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2010."

Then in the installer it was important to put a check on "*Install the designer components for Visual Studio 2010*"

[image]

After that opening Visual Studio again and I got SQLite Database File under the data source options.

Comment: Thank you! funny I tried a custom install first and had everything checked and never saw the screenshot you supplied and it did not work... did a full install and then got to that screen and it seemed to work! Thanks for supply the answer!

Comment: Just to remark that "Install the designer components for Visual Studio 2010" checkbox presents only in installer for 32-bit Windows (not in 64-bit)

Comment: The tick box you show is missing when I tried installing it. How do I install it? It is still missing from visual studio when I finish running all the installers.