# Missing PostgreSQL data provider in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, postgresql, datasource

I'd like to continue from my previous question [SQLite database file type missing from Visual Studio 2010 data source options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460090/sqlite-database-file-type-missing-from-visual-studio-2010-data-source-options)

I want to crete a connection to PostgeSQL database this time and facing the same issue about a missing data source.

So far I have:

1. Installed the PostgreSQL server and a new database created
2. Under Visual Studio 2010, inside PMC, I run "Install-Package Npgsql"
3. In the app.config file I registered the Npgsql Data Provider by adding the DbProviderFactories block

Then, I try to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model from Visual Studio by generating it from the database (using Entity Framework 4). I'm trying to make a connection to the PostgreSQL database but I don't see how to connect to it. Below what I have:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 data source options]

**How do I make a connection to PostgreSQL database?**

Answer (score 0):

finally, we've got it:)

Please see the link:
https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider

Comment: Links can go dead, so link-only answers are [discouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please copy the relevant information into your answer.