# Cannot select SQLite Database File as data source in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to connect my project to a SQLite database. I am following [this](http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/Using_SQLite_within_Visual_Studio) tutorial, as well as having looked at some others via Google search.

My problem is that when I right-click 'Data Connections' and select 'Add Connection', there is no option for 'SQLite Database Connection' available.

I have downloaded the ADO.NET provider as suggested. But this hasn't helped.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite database file type missing from Visual Studio 2010 data source options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460090/sqlite-database-file-type-missing-from-visual-studio-2010-data-source-options)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without point and click data connections.

I did a quick google search and came across this: [nice tutorial from another dev site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application/)

I hope it helps